# ec2_ami_copy - Unhandled exception - error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm trying to encrypt an AWS AMI, but getting the below error.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "aws_access_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "aws_secret_key": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "description": "",
            "ec2_url": null,
            "encrypted": true,
            "kms_key_id": null,
            "name": "euwestami1",
            "profile": null,
            "region": "us-west-2",
            "security_token": null,
            "source_image_id": "ami-xxxxx",
            "source_region": "us-west-2",
            "tags": {
                "Name": "MyNewWestAMI",
                "Service": "TestWestAMIService"
            },
            "validate_certs": true,
            "wait": false,
            "wait_timeout": "1200"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Unhandled exception. (('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')))"
}
```

My actual code is:

```
---
- name: encytption
  hosts: localhost
  remote_user: root
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: copying and encrypting an ami
    ec2_ami_copy:
      region: "us-west-2"
      aws_access_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      aws_secret_key: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      encrypted: yes
      source_region: "us-west-2"
      source_image_id: "ami-28e07e50"
      wait: no
      name: euwestami1
      tags:
        Name: MyNewWestAMI
        Service: TestWestAMIService
    register: instance
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, although you probably don't need remote_user: root.  What version of ansible are you using?